# How to add new row into listview?

Tags: sql-server

i have a listview with column ID and Barcode..
how to insert a new row  into the listview when 'Add' button is click?
The new data that we insert will also be saved into my database.
btw, i am using Visual Studio 2008 C#

Answer (score 0):

Insert in Listview

```
ListViewItem lstview = new ListViewItem(yourColumnIDValue);
listView1.Items.Add(lstview);
lstview.SubItems.Add(yourBarcodeValue);
```

Insert in your DB.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable(ColumnID,Barcode)
VALUES (yourColumnIDValue,yourBarcodeValue);
```